# Trying to change new_manager.user.is_employee = False and set it as new_manager.user.is_manager = True , but not working

Tags: django, forms, validation

Upon converting a user into a manager, I need to set 'is_employee = False' and 'is_manager = True'. The process appears to be quite straightforward, but I can't get it to work.

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name} as {self.username}'


class Manager(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user_profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
business_unit = models.OneToOneField(BusinessUnit, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
previous_business_units = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
manager_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
manager_created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.first_name} {self.user.last_name}'
```

views.py

```
@login_required
@admin_required
def manager_create_view(request):
form = ManagerCreationForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ManagerCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_manager = form.save(commit=False)
        group = Group.objects.get(name='Manager')
        new_manager.user.groups.add(group)
        new_manager.user.is_employee = False
        new_manager.user.is_manager = True
        new_manager = form.save()
        new_manager = form.cleaned_data.get('user')
        messages.success(request, f'{new_manager} is now a Manager!')
        return redirect ('list-managers')
    messages.error(request, 'Something went wrong, please check the hilighted field(s)')
context = {
    'title': 'Create Manager',
    'form': form
}
return render(request, 'managers/manager-form.html', context)
```

I tried using signals as well but, no luck.

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from accounts.models import User, Manager
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Manager)
def change_user_type(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  if created:
    instance.user.is_manager = True
    instance.user.is_employee = False
```

Trying to learn on my own, so any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the *user* of the manager, not only the manager itself, so:

```
@login_required
@admin_required
def manager_create_view(request):
    form = ManagerCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ManagerCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_manager = form.save()  # 🖘 save the manager object
            group = Group.objects.get(name='Manager')
            user = new_manager.user
            user.groups.add(group)
            user.is_employee = False
            user.is_manager = True
            user.save()  # 🖘 save the user object
            messages.success(request, f'{user} is now a Manager!')
            return redirect('list-managers')
        messages.error(request, 'Something went wrong, please check the hilighted field(s)')
    context = {
        'title': 'Create Manager',
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'managers/manager-form.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks @Willem
"save the user of the manager...." is it because is_employee and is_manager are fields in the User model?

Comment: @Kim: yes, that is also the table where these are stored, so you need to make an UPDATE query for that table (and thus save the object of *that* model). If you save a model, Django will *not* follow foreign keys and save these as well, that would often be inefficient as well, since often the fields on foreign key objects do not change.